# simulating timer in java

Tags: java, swing, timer

I am trying to simulate a timer. So upon clicking button in the `JFrame` form, I want the timer to countdown from say 10 to 0. I want it to be exactly 10s. I don't want to find elapsed time of any codes as whatever codes I have found so far give elapsed time. For example using `System.nanoTimer()`.

I tried doing this:

```
 private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:timer
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();    
    // ... the code being measured ...  
    long targetTime=startTime+10000;
    while(System.nanoTime()<targetTime)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,targetTime-System.nanoTime());
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"time's up");
}
```

But of course it hardly shows the time left once or twice. Can someone help me with the logic?

Comment: *"I am trying to simulate a timer."* ..why? Or more to the point, why not use a Swing `Timer`? For accuracy, fire the timer much faster than once a second, and check the nano time as to whether to act (change the time). See also [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) It also appears that a modal (blocking dialog appearing on every loop of the `while`) will mess things up. For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

10000 nanosec's is 10 miliseconds and that is is 1/100 of one second.
Use:

```
System.currentTimeMilis
```

instead